# Golang imported fields do not act the same as standard field declarations

Tags: go, mgo

I'm going to try to simplify the problem down rather than bring the whole project into scope so if you have questions I'll try to update with more information.

I have 3 structs I'm working with:

```
type Ticket struct{
  ID bson.ObjectID `json:"id" bson:"_id"`
  InteractionIDs []bson.ObjectId `json:"interactionIds" bson:"interactionIds"`
  TicketNumber int `json:"ticketNumber" bson:"ticketNumber"`
  Active bool `json:"active" bson:"active"`
  // Other fields not included
}

type TicketInteraction struct{
  ID bson.ObjectID `json:"id" bson:"_id"`
  Active bool `json:"active" bson:"active"`
  // Other fields not included
}

type TicketLookupTicket struct{
  Ticket
  Interactions []TicketInteraction `json:"interactions" bson:"interactions"`
}
```

Then I have an mgo pipe that I'm working with to 'join' the two collections together

```
var tickets []TicketLookupTicket
c := mongodb.NewCollectionSession("tickets")
defer c.Close()

pipe := c.Session.Pipe(
  []bson.M{
    "$lookup": bson.M{
      "from": "ticketInteractions",
      "localField": "interactionIds",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "interactions",
    }
  },
)
pipe.All(&tickets)
```

Now tickets should be populated with the result from the database, but what is actually happening is only the interactions within each ticket has been populated. It ends up looking something like this:

```
[
  {
    ID: ObjectIdHex(""),
    InteractionIDs: nil,
    TicketNumber: 0,
    Active: false,
    // Other Fields, all with default values
    Interactions: []{
      {
        ID: ObjectIdHex("5a441ffea1c9800148669cc7"),
        Active: true,
        // Other Fields, with appropriate values
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Now if I manually declare some of the Ticket structs fields inside the TicketLookupTicket struct, those fields will start populating. Ex:

```
type TicketLookupTicket struct{
  Ticket
  ID bson.ObjectId `json:"id" bson:"_id"`
  TicketNumber int `json:"ticketNumber" bson:"ticketNumber"`
  Active bool `json:"active" bson:"active"`
  Interactions []TicketInteraction `json:"interactions" bson:"interactions"`
}
```

Now ID, TicketNumber, and Active will start populating, but the remaining fields won't.

Can anyone explain why the imported Ticket fields aren't behaving the same as the declared fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Per the documentation](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson#Unmarshal), you need to add the `inline` tag to the field:

```
type TicketLookupTicket struct{
  Ticket `bson:",inline"`
  Interactions []TicketInteraction `json:"interactions" bson:"interactions"`
}
```

> `inline`    Inline the field, which must be a struct or a map.
>              Inlined structs are handled as if its fields were part
>              of the outer struct. An inlined map causes keys that do
>              not match any other struct field to be inserted in the
>              map rather than being discarded as usual.

By default, it assumes that the embedded field `Ticket` should be filled by an object at `TicketLookupTicket.Ticket`.

Comment: I can't add this as the accepted answer for another 5 minutes, but thank you so much. Immediately fixed the problem.